# Is it possible to discern the quality of web data from networks derived from it?

Tags: graphs, data-mining

One topic I've recently looked at is [co-occurence networks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Co-occurrence_networks) formed from [Twitter](https://twitter.com/) tweets.  This is how I felt after looking at the tweets of random people:

[image: Professor Farnsworth: "I don't want to live on this planet anymore."]

This leads me to the question:

> **Question**: Is it possible to discern the quality of web data from networks derived from it?

*A hypothetical situation*: Suppose we have two networks of comparable size derived from two different web sources: Network X is from a high-quality source (perhaps government documents) and Network Y is from a low-quality source (perhaps some random blog).  *Which network is from a higher quality source: Network X or Network Y?*

I'm intentionally leaving out specifics about the networks in this question, since I'm intending this to be more of a proof-of-concept style question.

Comment: Can you come up with some heuristics (known as "random guesses" under friends)? Does the average degree of the nodes (or their distribution) tell you something? Number of leaves (nodes of degree 1), number of disconnected nodes (degree 0)? Perhaps the number of connected components says something? In any case, this looks more like an experimental endeavor... get some data, do regression, publish... profit!

Comment: I suppose I could hazard a heuristic.  E.g. perhaps lower quality sources will re-use the same terms more frequently than higher quality sources.  This might affect the degree distribution of co-occurence networks.  But it's just speculation, and I'd like to know what (if anything) has been done already.

Comment: I'd guess that the quality metrics will depend a lot on the type of network. Even among the SE sites, I'd hazard that _without "quality" differences_ the clustering of words will be vastly different here and e.g. at http://math.stackexchange.com or http://www.stackoverflow.com (the subject matters there are much broader).